# With autorun on, how can I ensure click-to-move kicks in when I click on an object or NPC?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I was forced to reinstall my game after the MoP patch came out.

I used to have my preferences set up in a way where I could put autorun on, but when I right-clicked an NPC or an object, click-to-move would kick in and it would walk me to that object and stop me at it.

If I try doing that now with click-to-move enabled, not only will I not turn in the direction where I've clicked, but I also won't stop walking.

This is frustrating me a lot. How can I get the original functionality back?

Comment: I think it's an option in your key bindings. Been years since I've played WoW though.

Comment: Were you using one mouse button for all of that?

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this out, and with *Click to Move* on I still can't bind the right mouse button (used for Click to Move) to autorun.

I suspect you had two different settings - Click to Move which works as you described, and *Toggle Autorun* under Key Bindings, in the Movement Keys section, bound to something else (maybe Middle Mouse, which is bindable).

Comment: Nope, got auto-run set to the tilde key. I tried it on one of mt other computers that had the same settings before, looks like it doesn't work anymore with the MoP patch.

Answer (score 1):

It may be as simple as enabling "click to move" under mouse settings in interface. By default, that command is off. I can still do it. I have toggle autorun on one of my side buttons, and right click turns it off and sends me over to wherever I clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Toggle Autorun key - Numlock
or the Toggle run/walk key - NumPad /

If I press Autorun and then right click somewhere to move, my character moves to where I clicked and stops running.
If Toggle run/walk is used the the same thing, just walking.

Or you could have mapped Right Click to something else? Go through your key mappings to check. If you don't want to scroll through the whole list just click on an unused option and change it to Right Click. It will tell you if it used to be bound to something else. Then remove that key binding and you will have right click back to normal!

Answer (score 0):

I play WoW a lot and i started playing around TBC and this happened to me aswell. If this happens by clicking a interactive object (npc's corpses, or quest objects) it will auto walk you towards the desired interactive object. As if you click on the ground anywhere and it moves you without you wanting to go to your interface or system settings and scan through the sections until you find "click to move" if it ticked that is the problem. If it is not ticked, report this issue to Blizzard directly. If they cant help it must be a program on your computer being messed up with WoW whilst it is active.